# Spring boot + gradle + tomcat hello world app not working

Tags: spring, tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

I am trying to implement a basic hello world web application using spring boot, gradle and tomcat. I have following java classes. When I execute "./gradlew clean tomcatRunWar" tomcat just starts but unable to access.

What could be the issue?

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.8'
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.6.RELEASE'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'tomcat'

mainClassName = "au.com.aeas.config.WebAppInitializer"

war {
    baseName = ''
    version =  '0.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.42",
        "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:7.0.42"
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:7.0.42") {
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
    }

    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.5.RELEASE'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.1.6.RELEASE")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.1.6.RELEASE")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '1.6' }
```

1. WebAppInitializer.java

   ```
     @EnableAutoConfiguration
     @ComponentScan("au.com.aeas.web.controller")
     @Controller
     public class WebAppInitializer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(WebAppInitializer.class).run(args);
     }

     @Bean
     public ApplicationSecurity applicationSecurity() {
        return new ApplicationSecurity();
     }

     @Bean
     public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
     }

     @Bean
     public AuthenticationSecurity authenticationSecurity() {
        return new AuthenticationSecurity();
     }

     @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
     protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends
       WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

       @Autowired
       private SecurityProperties security;

       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
               .formLogin();
       }
     }

     @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 10)
     protected static class AuthenticationSecurity extends
       GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password")
               .roles("USER");
      }
     }
    }
   ```
2. HelloController.java

   ```
   @Controller
   public class HelloController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView hello() {
       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
       modelAndView.addObject("message", "charith");
       modelAndView.setViewName("hello");
       return modelAndView;
     }

   }
   ```
3. hello.jsp

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>Hello world page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>${message}</h1>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: any exception in console? what is the error message you getting when you trying to access?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a `ServletContextInitializer` anywhere, so my guess is `gradle bootRun` (or running your main method) would work, but deploying to Tomcat would not. A basic `ServletContextInitializer` is easy to write and well documented (e.g. here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war-maven/). Example:

```
public class WebInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(WebAppIninitializer.class);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run it on tomcat then why not to package it into jar file and use an embedded tomcat? Of course you will have to change a prject structure a little bit.